# Changing how pirate bay scope opens results

Tags: unity, lenses, scopes

I honestly don't entirely know what I am doing but I am trying to make the Pirate Bay Scope open its results with Acestream Player.  One of the problems being Acestream doesn't know how to handle magnetic links.

The original code is:

```
def on_activate_uri (self, scope, uri):
    if uri.startswith("more"):
        results = self.scope.props.results_model
        page = uri.split('__')[2]
        search = uri.split('__')[1]
        results.remove(results.get_iter_at_row(results.get_n_rows()-1))
        self.update_results_model (search, results, page)
        return Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.SHOW_DASH, goto_uri="")
    else:
        print uri
        GLib.spawn_command_line_async('gvfs-open %s' % uri)
        return Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.HIDE_DASH, goto_uri='')
```

I have modified one line so it is:

```
GLib.spawn_command_line_async('aria2c -d ~/.torrents --on-download-complete ~/.torrent.sh --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true \'%s\'' % uri)
```

I am using aria2c to connect to the magnetic link and download a torrent file, and once the file has been downloaded aria2c runs a bash script which opens the torrent file with Acestream.  This process works fine on the command line.  I am guessing my syntax is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I have kind of made progress by changing the code to `GLib.spawn_command_line_async("gnome-terminal -x aria2c -d /_fullpath_/.torrents --on-download-complete=/_fullpath_/.torrent.sh --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true '%s'" % uri)` it will create the torrent path and open Acestream for a few moments before shutting it down.

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked by spelling out each command I wanted to run using Popen the final implementation follows.

```
    else:
        print uri
        subprocess.Popen('rm /path/.torrents/*', shell=True)
        subprocess.Popen('gnome-terminal -x aria2c --allow-overwrite=true -d /path/.torrents --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true \'%s\'' % uri, shell=True).wait()
        torrent = subprocess.check_output('ls /path/.torrents/*', shell=True).strip()
        GLib.spawn_command_line_async('acestreamplayer %s' % torrent)
        return Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.HIDE_DASH, goto_uri='')
```

Now I just need to parse out the adult hits.  It is for the family entertainment system after all.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly in the unity-lens-torrents I should place this code? And what to replace/delete?